# How to connect my Android phone? KDECONNECT?

Tags: applications

I have some pictures in my HUAWAY P 20 Lite. The Android version is 8.0. When connected through usb my Elementary 5.0 installation seems to notice the phone. But neither the Kdeconnect Indicator nor the file manager does not see the picture-files so I could download them to the pc :mad:

Answer (score 2):

> I can see a lot of stuff in the huawaylite but can not find just the pictures. Perhaps the best method for me would be to use Gmail to send them to myself and then download to my pc. Or use Dropbox or an other cloud :}

What exactly did you see after connecting the phone? *Usually* you should be able to browser the devices internal folder structure and find your pictures in some place like "Pictures" or "DCIM", but it might require a bit of browsing or getting used to the folder structure.

Apart from that:
* Yes, of course syncinc images using Google Drive or Dropbox would be an option. At least for Dropbox there should be a Linux sync client as well. As an alternative (if privacy matters to you), you might want to use a Nextcloud or something like this all along with the appropriate (Android, Linux) apps.
* You could go for a tool such as WiFi File Transfer (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smarterdroid.wififiletransfer) on Android. This essentially allows for starting a (web) server on your Android device and gives you an easy chance to download files (one or many) using your web browser.

But unless Huawei completely messed it up, you really shouldn't need to use these. Maybe, as an option, after connecting you might want to use the elementary file managers "find" facility to locate an image file by name, on the device, if they are hard to find.

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon your Android configuration on the Huawei device, as soon as you connect it via USB, the phone should prompt you with a question how to connect (something like "USB debugging", "file transfer" or "charge only"). Be sure to choose "file transfer" in this case, and you should be seeing the phone under "Devices" in the left bar of the file manager. Give it a try and get back in case this doesn't work. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your answer. It went as you described:

> the phone should prompt you with a question how to connect (something like "USB debugging", "file transfer" or "charge only"). Be sure to choose "file transfer" in this case, and you should be seeing the phone under "Devices" in the left bar of the file manager.

I can see a lot of stuff in the huawaylite but can not find just the pictures. Perhaps the best method for me would be to use Gmail to send them to myself and then download to my pc. Or use Dropbox or an other cloud :}

From the Softwarecenter I only found Kdeconnect. Any other program to try?

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for your interest on my problem. I have many years of interest of Linux as hobby only.

It seems to me that the best method is to use something like Dropbox. This time I tried Pcloud but although I saw some one to recommend it to linux user for example the pcloudDRIVE I downloaded does not work in this my Elementary 5.0 installation.

I go on :)

Answer (score 0):

I had installed kde-connect  easily via terminal
just add

```
 sudo apt install kdeconnect
```

and here is the app

KDE Connect on Google Play: [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kde.kdeconnect_tp&hl=en)

[Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NPl6JBAxQo4)